# What is the document might be as "Evidence of family members remaining in your home country whilst you travel" for Standard Visitor Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

Applying for Standard Visitor Visa from Russia while being Russian. 
In case I have children and wife, I apply the marriage certificate and children birth certificates with the rest of documents.

Is that ***the evidence of family members remaining in your home country whilst you travel***? 
If it is not please let me know what kind of document it might be? I have not managed to find an answer to that question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not all of the documents listed are actually *requirements*. If you don't have family members remaining behind (and I'm assuming your wife & children are accompanying you) then there's nothing for you to submit here. Just make sure you do submit enough documentation to convince them that you'll be coming back home after your visit...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These would be documents related to your immediate relations who will not be traveling with you. They may consist of:

- Proof of your marriage
- Passport/National ID of spouse
- Birth certificate(s) of your kid(s)
- Proof of address of your spouse and kids
- School enrolment of kid(s) or spouse which they would continue in your absence
- Current employment of your spouse

If you're not married then it gets a bit difficult. You may have to show elderly parents who need you for caretaking and some documents in relation to this would be:

- IDs of parents proving age
- Proof of your and their address to establish you're living together
- Proof of any medical condition (if the caretaking if for medical reasons)
- A draft letter supporting your case (optional or if required)

Along with this, although it may seem evident, there shouldn't be a visa application for them because you will be using these relations as a guarantee that you will come back to your home country. :-D

If the parents/spouse/kids scenarios aren't applicable to you then it would be better to use other ties-to-home-country option.

Comment: please let me know where you find such a list?

Comment: Mostly from personal experience, friends & family experiences, general reading. But certainly, the country's immigration or visa website/forms/instructions do give a general idea e.g. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents